# Align non-geographical leaflet map maxBounds to the bottom of the container

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, zooming

I am creating a non-geographical map with leaflet, which shows a ski resort.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/exophunk/ruzgeqL4/

I am using `map.fitBounds(bounds)` to fit the map to the container and `map.setMaxBounds(bounds)` to make sure you can't pan outside the map.

This works perfect when zooming in, but as long as the map is smaller than the viewport height, I would like to "align" the whole thing to the bottom of the container, so the map never moves away from the bottom of the container. As it is a mountain, it is pretty obvious.

I achieved this by adding an offset to the maxBounds, as you can see in this example (blue box = max bounds):

https://jsfiddle.net/exophunk/05cq3rzt/

The problem with this approach is, that you can now pan into the "empty sky" when zooming in, while I would actually like to keep the maxBounds as in the first example, so it also restricts movement upwards.

I think this would mean I would need to resize the max bounds while zooming in maybe? But there, I messed up coordinate systems and containers and wasn't able to do this properly.

How can I make sure the map always sticks to the container bottom while keeping the original max bounds, if possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the default wheel zoom and check if the zoom mousepoint is in the bounds, else zoom to the center of the bounds/map:

```
map.scrollWheelZoom._performZoomOrg = map.scrollWheelZoom._performZoom;
map.scrollWheelZoom._performZoom = function(e){
     var mouse = map.scrollWheelZoom._lastMousePos;
     var llpixel = map.containerPointToLatLng(mouse)
     if(!bounds.contains(llpixel)){
        map.scrollWheelZoom._lastMousePos = map.unproject([container.clientWidth/2,  mapHeight]);
     }
     map.scrollWheelZoom._performZoomOrg();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/c04ngftj/

Comment: Thank you. I see that this only adjusts zooming, I can still pan to the "empty sky". Also as it's mainly a mobile app, it needs to work with touch gestures aswell. Can I do something like this aswell by overwriting panning and touch zoom? Or is there a more universal approach to actually use the bounds like normal (my first fiddle) and make the bottom alignment differently.

Comment: I think I need to resize the bounds when zooming maybe?, but I don't know how to get the correct coordinates